# Character ranges with character escapes

Tags: javascript, regex

From my understanding, this

```
/[\d-X]/
```

is not allowed by the standard:

> The abstract operation CharacterRange takes two CharSet parameters A and B and performs the following:
>   1. If A does not contain exactly one character or B does not contain exactly one character then throw a SyntaxError exception... (http://es5.github.io/#x15.10.2.15)

However, some (most?) browsers treat `-` as an ordinal character if it's preceded/followed by an escape, so that the above matches digits, dash and X:

```
var re = /[\d-X]/g;

for(var i = 0, r = ""; i < 0x10000; i++) {
    var s = String.fromCharCode(i);
    if(!s.replace(re, ''))
        r += s;
}
console.log(r) // -0123456789X
```

Questions:

- Is this behavior observable in all engines? (I've tested latest Webkit and Firefox)
- Are there any explanations why they decided to violate the standard (in the docs, sources, mailing lists etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think note 3 under [*15.10.2.16 NonemptyClassRangesNoDash* in the standard](http://es5.github.io/#x15.10.2.16) answers it:

> A - character can be treated literally or it can denote a range. It is
>   treated literally if it is the first or last character of ClassRanges,
>   the beginning or end limit of a range specification, or immediately
>   follows a range specification.

In this case I think the `immediately follows a range specification` applies.

Some other examples: `[a-f-h]` `[\s--9]` `[\w\d-\s]`

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. The words "range specification" are not defined elsewhere in the standard, so the implementers are free to make their own decisions here.